# How to scroll beyond fixed position elements on a page with TOC without using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Any ideas how to fix this problem: On a page with TOC (table of contents) with links pointing to hashtags within the same page, when the browser scrolls down other fixed position elements hide it. The browser should scroll further down to avoid being hidden by the fixed elements.

Fiddle to demonstrate this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/fcro6mth/ Click Section One or Section Two - the browser scrolls down to it but its hidden by the fixed header

Solution with JS: https://jsfiddle.net/fcro6mth/1/

Can you think of any solution that doesn’t involve JS?

Code from JS fiddle:

HTML:

```
<header>
    This is the fixed position header
    <nav>
        <a href="#section1">Section One</a>
        <a href="#section2">Section Two</a>
        <a href="#section3">Section Three</a>       
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="body">
    This is the body.
    <section id="section1">This is section one</section>
    <section id="section2">This is section two</section>
    <section id="section3">This is section three</section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
section {
    background: lightgrey;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    height: 300px;
}

header {
    background-color: grey;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 0;
    color: white;
}

.body {
    margin: 70px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$("nav a").click(function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget),
        $scrollToTarget = $($target.attr("href")),
        $header = $("header"),
        prop = { 
            scrollTop:   $scrollToTarget.offset().top - $header.outerHeight(true)
        },
        speed = 1000;

    $('html, body').animate(prop, speed);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13555927/2112228

Nice example to make hidden anchors for offsetting your sections.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I just arrived at it as well: https://jsfiddle.net/fcro6mth/5/

Answer (score 1):

**Updated version of your fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/fcro6mth/4/

**Solution**

I wrapped your sections in div-wrappers gave them the IDs, padded them down and pulled them back up with a negative margin.

This results in the exact same appearance, but the links do what you want them to do.

**Example:**

```
HTML:
<div id="section1" class="wrapper">
    <section >This is section one</section>
</div>

CSS:
.wrapper {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Comment: thats a lot of space between sections. I agree its a solution if that space is ok, but in my case its not... and the solution depends on that space being there.

Answer (score 1):

I have struggled with this issue a lot in designing a webpage with a combined banner / navbar of about 300px fixed at the top of a page full of short items linked to by anchor links from the website's home page.

The problem I have found with the "`margin-top: -XXpx; padding-top: XXpx`" approach is that the invisible padding overlaid the preceding item, meaning that active content (ie. links) were blocked.  I overcame this by applying positioning to the anchored elements and setting the z-index so that the first item was on top of the stack with each subsequent item lower in the stack - like this:

CSS

```
.anchored-element {
padding-top: 300px;
margin-top: -300px;
position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="anchored-element" style="z-index: 99">FIRST ITEM</div>
<div class="anchored-element" style="z-index: 98">SECOND ITEM</div>
<div class="anchored-element" style="z-index: 97">THIRD ITEM</div>
```

... etc

This provided a fix that worked for me across Firefox, Safari and Chrome on my desktop, and on my iOS devices.  I hope this helps others tackle this very frustrating issue in bootstrap!