# How do I offset where my fixed navbar items takes target id element?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have a fixed navigation bar on my website that stays at the top with links that take me to different sections further down the page. However, because my fixed navbar has a height of 60px, the beginning 60px of every section is covered up. How would I offset where my links take me by 60px using either HTML or CSS? and I did target element {top:60px, content:''} but its talking to gap between two section how can I solve this and also referred this [How do I offset where my fixed nav bar takes me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555709/how-do-i-offset-where-my-fixed-nav-bar-takes-me) but its not works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a separate element before the content you are scrolling to and add `60px` gap there.
`HTML` will be like

```
<span class="target" id="who_we_are"></span>
<h1>Who We Are</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>

<span class="target" id="join_us"></span>
<h1>Join Us</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.</p>
```

And css will be like

```
.target{
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution on [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/fixed-headers-on-page-links-and-overlapping-content-oh-my/):

```
    /* Height of your menu = 60px */
    html {
          scroll-padding-top: 60px;
    }

    body {
          margin-top: 60px;
    }
```

It's pretty well supported -- see [Caniuse Search scroll-padding-top?](https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll-padding-top)